# addeventlistener Shopping Cart does not work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, cart

I'll keep things simple, within my jsfiddle I have a shopping cart using javascript. What I want is for somebody to click the button and it will add an item to the cart. Unfortunately the function will not invoke AdditemtoCart unless it's outside the function which is driving me nuts. Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/w2z3rb9h/51/

```
<div  id="cart" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">
<div id="money">
$</div>
<div id="length">
Items
</div>
</div>

<button name="button" id="addItem">
Add Item
</button> 

HTML Code above

// [(START)Cart]-------->
var cart = [];
// [(END)Cart]---------->


// [(START)Factory]-------->
var Item = function(name, price, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.count = count;
};
// [(END)Cart]-------------->


// [(START)Adding Items to Cart]-------->
function addItemToCart(name, price, count){
for (var key in cart) {
 if (cart[key].name === name) {
         cart[key].count += count;
         cart[key].price += price;
         return;
     }
}

var item = new Item(name, price, count);
cart.push(item);
}
// [(END)Adding Items to Cart]---------->


// [(START)Remove Item From Cart]-------->
function removeItemFromCart(name,price) {
 for(var key in cart) {
     if(cart[key].name === name) {
        cart[key].count --;
        cart[key].price -= price;
     if(cart[key].count === 0) {
        cart.splice(key,1);
     }
        break;
     } 

 }
}
// [(END)Remove Item From Cart]-------->


// [(START)Remove All Item From Cart]-->
function removeItemFromCartAll(name){
  for (var key in cart){
      if(cart[key].name === name){
      cart.splice(key, 1);
      break;
      }

  }
}
// [(END)Remove All Item From Cart]---->



function call() {
addItemToCart("Apple", 1.2, 1);
 alert("It works");
}


document.getElementById("addItem").addEventListener("mousedown", call);



// [(START)Get Cart Amount] ----------->
function cartlength() {
var x = 0;
for (var key in cart) {
  x += cart[key].count;
}
 document.getElementById("length").innerHTML  = "Items:" + x;
}
//Invoked:Get Cart Amount
cartlength();
// [(END)Get Cart Amount] ----------->


// [(START)Price] ------------------->
function cartprice() {
var y = 0;
for (var key in cart) {
  y += cart[key].price;
}
 document.getElementById("money").innerHTML  = "$" + y;
}
//Invoke: Price
cartprice();
// [(END)Price] --------------------->
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `addItem` button it invokes `call` function, and inside `addItemToCart` and `alert` also invoked. You can test it adding alert inside `addItemToCart`. Item is inside `cart` array now. And you need to update `cart` div, invoking `cartlength` and `cartprice` functions. Update `call` method this way:

```
function call() {
  addItemToCart("Apple", 1.2, 1);
  cartlength();
  cartprice();
  alert("It works");
}
```

Comment: Dima, stupid me just realized I didn't invoke the cartlengh() and cartprice() again, hence why it was not displaying. Thanks for answering my noobish question, it was giving me a lot of distress till you came and save the day. You the man!